# Using WebImage() with .gif images

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use WebImage with an uploaded .gif image.

```
WebImage file = new WebImage(fullFilePath + ".gif");
file.Save(newImage);
```

I get an error stating:

```
System.Exception: A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.
```

How can I use a .gif with the WebImage class?

Comment: Why do you need to use this class specifically? You may have an easier time with Bitmap or Image if all you're doing is saving the file.

Comment: Actually, I am adding a watermark and creating thumbnails too.

Comment: From http://forums.asp.net/t/901961.aspx/1 ""A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format."  In that case, you need to create a Graphics instance from a blank bitmap of the same dimensions, and then draw the old bitmap onto the canvas.  I ran into this problem when opening a GIF image and attempting to add the watermark. "